# How do you avoid taking damage from Vi's Ultimate with Qss or cleanse?

Tags: league-of-legends

I rarely build [qss](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver_Sash)(Quicksilver sash) and almost never take [cleanse](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanse). Which leads me to ask when Vi targets you with her ultimate (Assault and Battery) when should you use [qss](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver_Sash) or [cleanse](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanse) to avoid the knockup and damage from her ultimate?

Comment: you can stun her mid dash or block it with banshees

Comment: You cant use those two to block it

Comment: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vi look at the details. but the stun during the dash seems to be impossible.

Comment: The reason is that Animations in League can't be interrupted so if you can't a spell immediately before getting stunned (i.e. Animation actually starts, not cast time but the actual animation) you can seemingly negate the effects of CC (smaller animations will seem less helpful but if the animation is long enough e.g. Lux Laser it can make it seem the stun did nothing entirely. as the animation may last as long or almost as long as the CC itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assault and Battery is a knock up, knock up are impossible to cleanse.

The only way to cancel vi ult is by using a spell-shield (Banshee). Or by becoming untargetable or invulnerable.

Comment: last I checked qss can remove all debuffs how does it not include knockups there has to be some form of counter play aside from spell shield

Comment: Knock up is the only cc in the game that can't be reduced by any means. Tenacity doesn't affect it, and QSS can cleanse it. It's part of the mechanic since the beginning. It's the same for pull and knock back. http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crowd_control

Comment: Yeah that really sucks thank you. I had thought qss would work but because i have not really built it before i have never had the chance to try using it

Comment: @Broken_Code AFAIK knockup is not a debuff; it's a state.

Answer (score 2):

QSS or cleanse have no effect on this kind of spell.

To understand this, think of it this way, Vi's ultimate is an instant cast, once she used it you cannot cleanse it because it is not a DoT (Damage over Time) nor an effect, therefore it is NOT a debuff, however what you can do is preventing it from starting with a spell shield like a banshee's veil or Sivir's E.

Cleanse can work on things like Mordekaiser's ultimate or Vladimir because those are DoTs or effects, so you can remove the effect.

Answer (score 1):

The only ways to preventing Vi from knocking you up with her ult are basically Spellshields, CC Immunity and **Killing her before she reaches you**. Tenacity and Cleanse have absolutely no effect on reducing the ability so the only way to "reduce" it is by becomming immune to it.

The spellshield is available to every champion through Banshees Veil while Sivir and Nocturne have one as a skill on a rather low cooldown.

CC Immunity is rather rare and can only be obtained through either a Morgana shield (castable on every champion) or for Olaf himself through his ultimate. Spells Like the ultimate of Vi or Malphite will also give you CC Immunity for the duration. After the spell animation is finished you will still be CCed.

According to the Wiki Knockups are somehow [interruptable by using a cleanse effect and dashing](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Knockup#Airborne) but I have never actually seen this in 5 years of playing LoL.

Through the CC immunity that Vi gains while casting her Ultimate, you cannot interrupt her however her Q is interruptable and of course if you land a stun on her before she casts it, she won't be able to do so.

Invulnerability will work aswell so things like Zhonyas, Fizz E and Shaco R also interrupt her channel.

Comment: Note that CC immunity will not protect you from damage. You will not get knocked up but will take the damage.